Question regarding Grassmann manifolds
I am trying to understand the following:
The Grassmann manifold $G_k(n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as all $k$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Here is a way to construct $G_k(n)$:
Let $F_k(n)$ denote the set of linearly independent $k$-tupels of vector sin $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e.
$F_k(n):=\{(x_1,...,x_k): x_1,...,b_k \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } x_1,...,x_k \text{ are linearly independent }\}$.
Obviously if we write $x_i$ column by column we can view $F_k(n)$ as a subset of $M(n \times k)$.
Now, if $A$ is a matrix $n \times k$ with lineary independent columns, we can choose $k$ rose in $A$ and consider the $k \times k$ submatrix $S_A$ of $A$. Since the columns were linearly independent, $det(S_A)\neq 0$. Note that:

Then the set of matrices for which that submatrix has determinant $\neq 0$ is an open subset of $M(n \times k)$.

For a matrix $A$, let $a_i$ denote it's $i$-th column.
Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $F_k(n)$ by
$A \sim B :\Leftrightarrow span\{a_1,...,k\}=span\{b_1,...,n_k\}$.

Then the set $\{[A]:A \in F_k(n)\}$ is the same as $G_k(n)$

Thus, there is a natural surjection $f:F_k(n) \rightarrow G_k(n)$.

Further $f:F_k(n) \rightarrow G_k(n)$ is smooth.


I do understand point 2 and 3.
About 1:
I don't know why the mentioned set should be open in $M(n \times k)$.
About 4:
If I am not wrong, the natural surjection should be $f: A \mapsto [A]$.
About 5:
I would like to show (or see a prove of) that $f$ is smooth.
So first I need a smooth structure.
To get that, I think the right approach here would be to use the "Smooth Manifold Chart Lemma".
I would need to that for $F_k(n)$ and $G_k(n)$.
Then it should be easy to see/show that $f$ is smooth.
But how do I use said lemma?
If I consider $F_k(n)$ to be a set, I need to find a collection of subsets $\{U_i\}$ of $F_k(n)$ together with maps $\phi_i:U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $, that satisfy the conditions of the Smooth Manifold lemma.
After that, I would need to do the same for $G_k(n)$.
But how do I get the subsets and the maps?
Could maybe anyone show me, how one (in detail) shows that $f$ is smooth?

I will try to say something. First of all about 1: the set should be open because it is related to the non-vanishing of the determinant of a kxk submatrix. Having $det\neq 0$ is an open condition (can you explain why in topological terms?) and it is interesting -for example- because it gives $Gr(n,k)$ a manifold structure.
On point 2, you are asking for $k$ dimensional subspace, this is not a bijection with bases for such a dimensional subspace, here -in point 2- he is "correcting" this via the proper equivalence relation. Consider the two families of k vectors, if their span is the same then they span the same $k$ dimensional subspace. Point 3 is basically the same argument.
In 4 you are right, it is just a quotient hence the map is a projection. For smoothness you should basically prove that what are you doing is just Gauss operation and these are obtained via matrix multiplications, hence smooth operation.
P.s.
I would suggest to check "Lectures on differential topology, Riccardo Benedetti" to shed some light on those topics in a more "educational" way.

Thanks for the feedback. Regarding the smoothness, could you maybe elaborate a little bit. I am not sure if I understand what you mean. I don't see why $f$ mapping a matrix to its equivalence class $[A]$  should have to do something with matrix multiplication.

I prefer the following approach: Given a $k$-plane $X$ and a transversal $(n-k)$-plane $Y$, Each  linear map $L: X \rightarrow Y$ determines a $k$-plane, namely the graph of $L$, $$G_L = \{ x + L(x):\ x \in X\}.$$ This defines a map $$ \mathcal{L}(X,Y) \rightarrow G_k(n), $$ where $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is the vector space of all inear maps from $X$ to $Y$. It is not hard to show that this map is injective and its image is the space of all $k$-planes transversal to $Y$, which is open in $G_k(n)$. Given a basis of $X$ and a basis of $Y$, there is a linear isomorphism $$ \mathcal{M}(k,n-k) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(X,Y), $$ where $\mathcal{M}(k,n-k)$ is the vector space of all $k$-by-$(n-k)$ matrices. This defines a coordinate chart on an open subset of $G_k(n)$. It is now straightforward to identify a finite set of such charts that covers $G_k(n)$, where the transition maps can be computed explicitly and shown to be diffeomorphisms.
